# What should be the authentication flow for desktop apps (electronjs)?

Tags: api, authentication, reactjs, desktop-application, electron

I have a web application (service). It have several routes for auth:

- Register: (post) `/auth/register`
- Login: (post) `/auth/login`
- Google oAuth2 API: (get) `/auth/google`

Google oAuth has flow: (get) `/auth/google` -> (redirect to) google oauth service -> (redirect to) `/auth/google/callback` -> register or login

At the moment, the web application does not have any of the implemented API on based `JWT` or `oAuth`. Only the `cookie`.

Now I want to make a desktop client for the web application via `electon` with `react + redux + react-router`. I am very little idea for authentication flow for a desktop app. Especially considering that authentication for oAuth providers must pass through my web application.

I never didn't write a desktop apps. Only web.